# Make Link to a Document more user friendly

Tags: content-type, hyperlink

The way Link to a Document works is that I need to go to the place where I want the link to appear. Click this content type and then provide the URL to the document in some remote location. This makes sense if the location is outside of my site collection, but it is annoying if the document is in my site collection. Is it possible to do one of two things:

1. when you select Link to a Document, you are given a choice of pasting in your link or browsing the documents in the site collection (while filtering our the locations and documents that current user does not have access to). This way the user would not have to know the URL of the document beforehand.
   Or
2. When I click on the document I have an option to send a copy of it to some location in the site collection. Add an option to make a link to the document at the target location and create a browsable menu of available locations.

If a tool like that already exists, great if not, how hard would it be to code something like this up?

Answer (score 1):

what we do is using a "AssetUrlSelector" which can be found in "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing" DLL.

Just include

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Tagprefix="CMS" %>
```

into your page and

```
                <CMS:AssetUrlSelector
                DefaultOpenLocationUrl="~SiteCollection/Gallery/"
                DefaultToLastUsedLocation="false"
                DisplayLookInSection="false"
                OverrideDialogFeatures="resizable: yes; status: yes; scroll: yes; help: no; dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:600px;"
                OverrideDialogTitle="Custom Picker Title"
                OverrideDialogDescription="Custom Picker Description"
                OverrideDialogImageUrl="~Site/PublishingImages/AssetPickerLogo.jpg"
                AssetTextClientID="AssetTextClientIdentityImage"
                ClientCallback="function(returnedUrl) { imgNews(returnedUrl) }"
                id="assetSelectedImageIdentity" 
                UseImageAssetPicker=true 
                runat="server" />
```

where to select URL.

Hope it helps,

Andrew